# if there an function to handle

Tags: laravel

All of my routes have a lang parameter and I need to unset it in the controller. How can I achieve this?

routes.php

```php
Route::prefix('{lang?}/admin')->attribute('namespace','Admin')->middleware('auth:web')->group(function () {
    Route::get('/branch/{branch}/products/create', ['uses' => 'BranchesController@createBranchProduct', 'as' => 'admin.branch.products.create']);
});
```

Controller:

```php
public function createBranchProduct(Branch $branch)
{
    $categories = Category::all();

    return View::make('admin.branches.products.new',['branch' => $branch,'categories'=>$categories]);
}
```

I'm getting the following error:
[image: Screenshot of the error]

Comment: please format your code properly! its difficult for someone to read.

Comment: You're going to have to rethink your approach. Having a first-position optional parameter for lang is not going to work when you have other, non-optional route parameters. They will (and clearly are) going to conflict with each other. Right now, your `{lang?}` parameter is being treated as a `Branch`, since it's optional.

Comment: which is the browser's route you've been trying to access?

Comment: yes i edited it thanq for caring

Comment: yes i need to know what are the mechanisms to solve this problem

Comment: This doesn't work; the route structure doesn't allow for lang to be null. Trying to navigate to `http://example.com/admin/branch/1` would be a 404 error. It only works if lang is explicitly provided: `http://example.com/en/admin/branch/1` for example. This is just what happens when you try to chain route parameters, but make a higher-level one optional.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer that I can make:

```
class baseController extends Controller {
  public function callAction($method, $parameters){
    unset($parameters['lang']);
    return parent::callAction($method, $parameters); //TODO: Change the autogenerated stub
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hello **turky eltahawy** and welcome to StackOverflow!

Let's take a look: you have grouped routes which have an optional parameter. Therefore, when you are calling `createBranchProduct` method, it expects two parameters: lang and instance/id of the Branch model.

What you can do is to accept 2 parameters in the `createBranchProduct` like this:

```php
public function createBranchProduct($lang = null, Branch $branch)
{
    $categories = Category::all();

    return View::make('admin.branches.products.new',['branch' => $branch,'categories'=>$categories]);
}
```

Comment: thanq for ur caring , yes i know that i can do this but by this i will put ($lang = null ) in all my my project function and i dont need this i need to handle this issue to let me avoid this way

Comment: I understand what you're talking about. Unfortunately, there isn't a way to pass a variable to all controllers. You can play with middleware to append the language path, but it won't be a good decision.